set height of element based on its content
I'm trying to set a height of my div so that it can be scrolled down and completely hidden at the top. So the height of element would have to be something like calc(parent_padding_top + max-content + 100vh), right? The idea is that I want to scroll just enough so that's completely hidden, but not really any further. Is there a way to do this?


.section {
 background-color: red;
 height: 200px;
 min-height: 200px;
 max-height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
 display: block;
 background-color: transparent;
}
<div class="section">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. 

<b>Now I should be able to scroll further until this text dissapears completely</b></p>
  </div>
</div>




height: auto?

How does that help?

If you make the container a grid one, you can use percentage and it will be relative to the height content.


.section {
 background-color: red;
 display: grid;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.content {
 background-color: transparent;
 height: calc(200% + 40px); /* consider the padding as well */
}
<div class="section">
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is some text, we don't really know how long that text will be, but it can be either very short or realy,  really long</p>
  </div>
</div>




It doesn't work as it should as it always sets the height to 200% of the section (+ padding). I edited the snippet, I hope it better explains the problem now.

@Malvinka check the code well, I am not defining any height on section so 200% of the content height which is the behavior you want
